# How to separate rows into columns based on variable number of pattern matches per row

Tags: r, regex, rows

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c("A","B"),
  date = c("31/07/2019", "31/07/2020"),
  x = c('random stuff "A":88876, more stuff',
         'something, "A":1234, more "A":456, random "A":32078, more'),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

I'd like to create as many new columns as there are matches to a pattern; the pattern is `(?<="A":)\\d+(?=,)`, i.e., "match the number if you see the string `"A":`on the left and the comma `,`on the right.

The problems: (i) the number of matches may vary from row to row and (ii) the maximum number of new columns is not known in advance.

What I've done so far is this:

```
df[paste("A", 1:max(lengths(str_extract_all(df$x, '(?<="A":)\\d+(?=,)'))), sep = "")] <- str_extract_all(df$x, '(?<="A":)\\d+(?=,)')
```

While `1:max(lengths(str_extract_all(df$x, '(?<="A":)\\d+(?=,)')))` may solve the problem of unknown number of new columns, I get a warning:

```
`Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, paste("A", 1:max(lengths(str_extract_all(df$x,  :
  replacement element 2 has 3 rows to replace 2 rows`
```

and the assignment of the values clearly incorrect:

```
df
  id       date                                                         x    A1   A2    A3
1  A 31/07/2019                        random stuff "A":88876, more stuff 88876 1234 88876
2  B 31/07/2020 something, "A":1234, more "A":456, random "A":32078, more 88876  456 88876
```

The correct output would be this:

```
df
  id       date                                                         x    A1   A2    A3
1  A 31/07/2019                        random stuff "A":88876, more stuff 88876   NA    NA
2  B 31/07/2020 something, "A":1234, more "A":456, random "A":32078, more  1234  456 32078
```

Any idea?

Comment: I think you need to `do.call(rbind` a list with adjusted lengths, before assigning it to the original data. Smaller example: Your data frame: `d = data.frame(x = 1:2)`; Result of regexing: `l = list(1, 1:3)`; Sequence along longest element: `s = 1:max(lengths(l))`; pad elements, row bind and assign: ``d[paste0("A", s)] = do.call(rbind, lapply(l, `[`, s))``. Or `stringi` convenience fun: `d[paste0("A", s)] = stringi::stri_list2matrix(l, byrow = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a somewhat pedestrian `stringr` solution:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

matches <- str_extract_all(df$x, '(?<="A":)\\d+(?=,)')
ncols   <- max(sapply(matches, length))

matches %>%
  lapply(function(y)  c(y, rep(NA, ncols - length(y)))) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  setNames(paste0("A", seq(ncols))) %>%
  cbind(df, .) %>%
  tibble()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   id    date      x                                            A1    A2    A3   
#>   <chr> <chr>     <chr>                                        <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 A     31/07/20~ "random stuff \"A\":88876, more stuff"       88876 <NA>  <NA> 
#> 2 B     31/07/20~ "something, \"A\":1234, more \"A\":456, ran~ 1234  456   32078
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is by no means pedestrian.Thanks a lot!